# How to look up a value in AngularJS and display data in HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I currently am getting to sets of JSON data back from a restul GET call. The first response set is used to build a HTML table of data. One of those values is an numeric ID from a data table in the DB.

In the other set of JSON data is a set of the values that correspond to the numeric id value in the first data set.

I'm trying to look up a value in the second set, based on the numeric value in the first set.

I've been able to accomplish this using a  tag and ng-options, but this particular column need to just be a static  tag with a data value.

My  tag looks like

```
<td><select id="basOrgs" class="form-control grid-input" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" ng-model="item.OrgUid" ng-options="org.OrganizationUid as org.OrganizationDisplay for org in Orgs"></select></td>
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to use the model item.OrgUid to look up a value in the Orgs data set to display Orgs.OrganizationDisplay based on the item.OrgUid value.

I've experimented with ng-repeat without any success.

```
<td ng-model="item.OrgUid" ng-repeat="org in Orgs track by org.OrganizationUid">{{org.OrganizationDisplay}}</td>
```

The item model looks like`{OrgUid: 123456, Active:'Y',`StartDate'}
The Org model looks like '{OrgUid: 123456, OrgDisplay: 'The Name of the Org'}

What I would like to do is display the OrgDisplay value in the  tag based on the item.OrgUid value.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
--Jim

Comment: Oh, so your `ng-options` isn't working right because `org.OrganizationDisplay` is not available in that json data set, but another one?

Comment: No actually the select tag is just for reference. It's working fine. It displays the dropdown select in the td row properly. What I'd like to do is just display the OrgDisplay value without using a drop down. Just static text such <td>{{OrgDisplay}}</td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have `$scope.orgs` in your controller, how about

```
<td ng-model="item.OrgUid" ng-repeat="org in Orgs track by org.OrganizationUid">{{lookup[org.OrganizationUid].OrganizationDisplay}}</td>
```

I'll edit this to include the right lookup code, but this is the idea.

You could make a lookup object to facilitate this:

```
var lookup = {};
for (var i = 0, len = orgs.length; i < len; i++) {
    lookup[array[i].OrganizationUid] = array[i];
}
```

Here is a working snippet that uses lookup between two "data sets".

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myController',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.Orgs = [{
      OrgUid: 1,
      OrgDisplay: 'Org 1'
    }, {
      OrgUid: 2,
      OrgDisplay: 'Org 2'
    }, {
      OrgUid: 3,
      OrgDisplay: 'Org 3'
    }];
    $scope.Items = [{
      OrgUid: 1,
      Active: 'Y',
      StartDate: "12/1/1984"
    }, {
      OrgUid: 2,
      Active: 'Y',
      StartDate: "12/1/1984"
    }, {
      OrgUid: 3,
      Active: 'Y',
      StartDate: "12/1/1984"
    }];

    $scope.lookup = {};
    for (var i = 0, len = $scope.Orgs.length; i < len; i++) {
      $scope.lookup[$scope.Orgs[i].OrgUid] = $scope.Orgs[i];
    }
  });
```

```css
.item {
  border:1px solid green; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController"> 
  
<body>
  <span class="item" ng-model="item.OrgUid" ng-repeat="item in Items">{{lookup[item.OrgUid].OrgDisplay}}</td>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok I made my solution to what I think your problem is, work.

Comment: Okay, we have it, the final answer is... There is no need for the ng-repeat in the <td> tag, the look up function solved the issue. This ended up being the final tag <td class="item" ng-model="item.OrgUid" >{{lookup[item.OrgUid].OrganizationDisplay}}</td> Thanks for toddmo for the answer!